# In Rails, is there an alternative solution to adding a column(s) to a large table in the database?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, migration

So, I was wondering if there was a clever way to handle adding a column to a MySQL table that contains a large amount of data. If I were to go the standard migration route, it would take roughly 6 hours. I wonder if there is a better solution for this.

One way we've avoided the long migration is create a new table/model and set up a delegation-type relationship in ActiveRecord. While this works nicely, it seems a bit wrong.

Should I just buck up and do the super long migration?

Comment: What do you mean by "large amount of data"? Text? To better answer the question you'll need to provide a little more info on the problem.

Comment: Some questions.. Do you need that data point for every record or can you set up a relational table that selectively joins on records where the data is needed? Is there a column-style table that you can set up to store arbitrary properties?  If you need it for every record than a new column may be warranted, but if you only need it for a subset of records than a relational approach may work.

Comment: @spullen - The table has roughly 28M rows in it.

Comment: @dethtron5000 - I don't need the data point for _every_ record, but I'd say about 95% of the entries will have it populated with data.

Answer (score 0):

I figure I'd let people know, I've decided to explore a Gem written by the folks over at SoundCloud to handle doing long migrations while keeping the database up (not locked).

https://github.com/soundcloud/lhm

Other solutions include Percona's pt-online-schema-change:

http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.1/pt-online-schema-change.html